# How to get text between two tokens

Tags: regex

I have an HTML document that we've generated using a 3rd party application. The problem we have is that it creates overrides for the styles in the HTML elements. So we end up with elements that are structured similar to this:

```
<p class="text ParaOverride-1">Hey</p>
<p class="text ParaOverride-2">now</p>
<p class="text ParaOverride-3">brown</p>
<p class="text ParaOverride-4">cow</p>
<p class="text ParaOverride-5">milk.</p>
```

I want all of the text between those two points - so that I can subsequently replace them with a blank to get the following output:

```
<p class="text">Hey</p>
<p class="text">now</p>
<p class="text">brown</p>
<p class="text">cow</p>
<p class="text">milk.</p>
```

The start token is p class=" and the end token would be the closing for the opening part of the p element.

Comment: The truth is that all html has to be parsed to correctly get the tags you need to check. This would be a big regex. Or you could use an html parser which uses a giga-gigantica block of invisible code (that you can't see) to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the task

```js
var a=document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML=a.replace(/\s[a-zA-Z]+\-\d/g,'');
```

```html
<body>
<p class="text ParaOverride-1">Hey</p>
<p class="text ParaOverride-2">now</p>
<p class="text ParaOverride-3">brown</p>
<p class="text ParaOverride-4">cow</p>
<p class="text ParaOverride-5">milk.</p>
<p class="text ParaOverride-1">Hey</p>
</body>
```

But parsing HTML with regex is a bad approach.

So, another approach is that

You want to remove the class other than `text`.

So, iterate over the elements and remove the other class.

Check this below

```js
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach( (x,i) => x.classList.remove("ParaOverride-"+(i+1)));
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<body>
<p class="text ParaOverride-1">Hey</p>
<p class="text ParaOverride-2">now</p>
<p class="text ParaOverride-3">brown</p>
<p class="text ParaOverride-4">cow</p>
<p class="text ParaOverride-5">milk.</p>
<p class="text ParaOverride-1">Hey</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Under `vi`, the replacement looks like this:

```
:%s/<p class="text \([^"]*\)"/<p class="text
```